# Return NULL if WHERE clause doesn't match - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been struggling with this most of the day now. I'm relatively early on in my Oracle SQL life, but I need to return results where `ldl_act_type.act_type_sc` is `'LID DATE LOGGED'`, and pull out the `ldl_act.date_actioned` for this as well.

However, I also need it to null these values if the `act_type_sc` isn't found (essentially still returning the row, because we need to see where the action hasn't been taken yet). I've been fiddling around with `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, but I don't think I quite grasp it enough. Hopefully the code below makes sense?

```
select 
    incident.incident_ref,
    incident.short_desc "Summary",
    serv_dept.serv_dept_n "Assigned SVD",
    inc_data.event_type,
    incident.date_logged "Date Logged",
    ldl_act.date_actioned "LID Date Logged",
    prp_act.date_actioned "Proposed LID Date",
    prp_act.remarks "Proposed LID Comments"
from 
    incident
    inner join serv_dept on incident.ass_svd_id = serv_dept.serv_dept_id
    inner join inc_data on incident.incident_id = inc_data.incident_id
    left join act_reg ldl_act on incident.incident_id = ldl_act.incident_id
    left join act_reg prp_act on incident.incident_id = prp_act.incident_id
    left join act_type ldl_act_type on ldl_act.act_type_id = 
ldl_act_type.act_type_id
    left join act_type prp_act_type on prp_act.act_type_id = 
prp_act_type.act_type_id
where 
    (inc_data.event_type = 'p')
    and (incident.date_logged > (sysdate-30))
    and (prp_act_type.act_type_sc = 'PROPOSED LID DATE')
    and (ldl_act_type.act_type_sc = 'LID DATE LOGGED')
```

Comment: Hi @Mark Adams. Can you please provide a sample of the output you are getting and a sample of the output you would like?

Comment: Hi Dwight, sure, I'm getting the below:

`INCIDENT_REF | Summary | Assigned SVD | EVENT_TYPE | Date Logged | LID Date Logged | Proposed LID Date | Proposed LID Comments
24 | test | assyst | p | 27 Nov 2018 10:35 | 29 Nov 2018 10:34 | 12 Jan 2019 00:00 | Test | P24`


There is one more line with the same information. There are about 23 others that should show, but with LID Date Logged and Proposed LID Date blanked out as they do not have an entry in ldl_act_type.act_type_sc as "LID DATE LOGGED". Problem is they would have more entries in the ldl_act_type table but with other text / dates.

Comment: Hi @Mark Adams. From the output you have shown me, that matches on your event_type condition, and your incident_datelogged condition. Are you sure you should see a null value with those where clauses? This question at this point would benefit greatly from an MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve more often than not in the process of trying to create a small example of the issue you manage to find the problem you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

So if I read this right, you want the row present if `ldl_act_type.act_type_sc = 'LID DATE LOGGED'` or if it's not present? It's a little confusing because you have `act_type` joined in twice and I'm not clear on what they have to do with each other.

So don't you just want to change your last clause to:

```
and ( ldl_act_type.act_type_sc = 'LID DATE LOGGED' OR 
      ldl_act_type.act_type_sc IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select incident.incident_ref,
incident.short_desc "Summary",
serv_dept.serv_dept_n "Assigned SVD",
inc_data.event_type,
incident.date_logged "Date Logged",
ldl_act.date_actioned "LID Date Logged",
prp_act.date_actioned "Proposed LID Date",
prp_act.remarks "Proposed LID Comments"
from incident
inner join serv_dept on incident.ass_svd_id = serv_dept.serv_dept_id
inner join inc_data on incident.incident_id = inc_data.incident_id
left join (select ldl_act.incident_id,ldl_act_type.act_type_sc from act_reg ldl_act 
            inner join act_type ldl_act_type on ldl_act.act_type_id = 
ldl_act_type.act_type_id) 
            as ldl_act_type on incident.incident_id = ldl_act.incident_id
left join (select prp_act.incident_id,prp_act_type.act_type_sc from act_reg prp_act 
            inner join act_type prp_act_type on prp_act.act_type_id = 
prp_act_type.act_type_id) 
            as prp_act_type on incident.incident_id = prp_act.incident_id
where (inc_data.event_type = 'p')
and (incident.date_logged > (sysdate-30))
and (prp_act_type.act_type_sc = 'PROPOSED LID DATE')
and (ldl_act_type.act_type_sc = 'LID DATE LOGGED')
```

Can You Try this?